# Rollup-plugin-img doesn't copy my images in dist folder

Tags: image, react-component, rollupjs

What I'm trying to do, with this simple config:

```
import image from 'rollup-plugin-img';
const packageJson = require("./package.json");

export default [
  {
    input: "src/index.ts",
    output: [
      {
        file: packageJson.module,
        format: "esm",
        sourcemap: true,
      },
    ],
    plugins: [
      resolve(),
      commonjs(),
      image({
        limit: 1000000,
        output: 'dist/assets',
        extensions: /\.(png|jpg|jpeg|gif|svg)$/,
      }),
      typescript({ tsconfig: "./tsconfig.json" }),
      json(),
      scss(),
      livereload(),
    ],-player'],
  },
];
```

is to copy my image into the dist folder. The image is a svg and it's actually stored in sub-folder of a react component `component/assets/image.svg`.
What is not happening is the copying of this image (imported by component with `import {image} from './assets/img/image.svg'`.

What am I missing?